# Microsoft excel Evaluate function returns a code error (-2146826273)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I'm using microsoft.office.interop.excel dll in my application .
when I execute the evaluation function with the below formula : `=IF(100000>15000,20%,IF(100000>12500,17.5%,IF(100000>10000,15%,IF(100000>7500,12.5%,IF(100000>5000,10%,0)))))*IF((AND(40>=20,23>=30)),15,2000)*LOG(IF(AND(3<>0,(1/3)>0.5),1000,2000))/IF(90<>0, IF((1/90)>0.5, 123456, 987654), 987654)-550-IF((OR(25>=20, 1000>=30)), 5000, 900)` .
I get a code error -2146826273. I test the formula using excel sheet and it worked perfectly. Please find below the executed code.

```
 public dynamic EvaluteFormula(string expressionFormula)
     {
         Application excelApp = new Application();
         return excelApp.Evaluate(expressionFormula);
     }
```

When I minimize the formula length by removing operators, it works perfectly. Has anyone ideas how to solve this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the minimized formula and how it differs from the original? It could be useful to know specifically which operators were removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string parameter length must less or equal to 255 characters. Here is what MSDN states for the [Application.Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) function which converts a Microsoft Excel name to an object or a value:

> A formula or the name of the object, using the naming convention of Microsoft Excel. The length of the name must be less than or equal to 255 characters.